# windows 10 stuck at sign in page

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, login-screen, safe-mode

I have bought a new Asus R512jb laptop and it's been a few weeks I'm using it with no problem, but a few days ago when I wanted to reboot it from sleep I faced a strange problem. When I saw the sign-in page and I clicked sign in (I have set no password) it just did nothing. I repeated this several times with same results happening again, so I searched the net and did the following:

1. I tried to boot from safe-mode which failed, although I tested two types of safe mode because even there it needed to sign in first.
2. Some websites said you can use restore points or similar options (which I couldn't do because I had no restore points on my system since the laptop was new)
3. I left the laptop off for some houres (seems ridiculous but I did it). I'm thinking of things I did before turning the laptop off, and I was trying to sync Windows Defender with my Microsoft account
4. I uninstalled recent updates via advanced troubleshooting (updates not features)
   5-I booted from the option which prevents anti_malware from running when system boots and still no result

I'm still trying different ways to solve the problem so I will update this post.

Any help is appreciated; thanks in advance.

Comment: please edit the question to replace "[spikey_richie: some text missing]". Not sure what you meant to type, but it was just `se`.

Comment: There was a Windows 10 20H2 update in your time frame above. Get the ASUS Driver App and update all your drivers. Do it manually from the ASUS Support site if you need to. You may need to start in Safe Mode to do this.

Comment: as I said I can't enter my desktop neither in safe mode nor in normal mode

Comment: Start with a bootable USB Key (Windows 10 or ASUS Recovery), back up your data and reinstall Windows. There is some chance there is a system drive issue.  Also, consider returning it to ASUS (still under warranty).

Comment: @John what does a system drive issue mean? is it realated to drivers or is it something else?

Comment: I used “system” drive to shorten SSD or HDD. That’s all.